# Calculate zoom level on google maps control in C#

Tags: c#, google-maps, zooming

I'm using [GoogleMap Control](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/releases/view/52051) have a collection of markers with Geo locations.  I can calculate the min and max lat longs and find the center point on where to center the map but I also need to calculate the zoom level programmatically. Does anyone how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this on an [issue page](http://googlemap.codeplex.com/workitem/11201) of the GoogleMap Control project site.  You have to inject javascript to do it.

```
    // Set the map to call zoomMap javascriptFunction
    GoogleMap.OnClientMapLoad = "zoomMap";

    // build zoomMap javascript function. I already know what my bounds are
    StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
    script.AppendFormat("<script>").AppendLine();
    script.Append("function zoomMap() {").AppendLine();
    script.AppendFormat("var sw = new GLatLng({0}, {1});", minLat, minLong).AppendLine();
    script.AppendFormat("var ne = new GLatLng({0}, {1});", maxLat, maxLong).AppendLine();
    script.AppendFormat("var bounds = new GLatLngBounds(sw, ne);").AppendLine();
    script.AppendFormat("var zoomLevel = GoogleMap.GMap.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds);").AppendLine();
    script.AppendFormat("GoogleMap.GMap.setZoom(zoomLevel);", GoogleMap.ClientID).AppendLine();
    script.Append("}").AppendLine();
    script.AppendFormat("</script>").AppendLine();

    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("map", script.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If your using v3 then simply

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

then extend your bounds for each marker:

```
bounds.extend(myLatLng);
```

and use this to automatically position and zoom

```
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: Ah just seen the GoogleMap control is not what I thought it was.  This may not be as helpful as I had hoped.  If you change you map to use the google.maps api this will definately do it for you